# ¿Cómo convertir una fecha de String a Date en Java?

Tags: java, date, eclipse

En un formulario estoy recogiendo la fecha de nacimiento del usuario.

He aquí un pequeño fragmento del código del controlador, en el cuál intento convertir la fecha de String a Date:

```
String startDate = request.getParameter("birthdaydate");
    
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.sql.Date fechaConvertida = null;

try {
    fechaConvertida = (Date) dateFormat.parse(startDate);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred"+ e.getMessage());
}
```

El error que me sale por consola es este:

```
Error occurredclass java.util.Date cannot be cast to class java.sql.Date (java.util.Date is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; java.sql.Date is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: fechaConvertida es de tipo java.sql.Date y tu le estas asignando un java.util.Date   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668329/convert-string-date-to-java-sql-date/15668370

Answer (score 1):

Tu error se debe a que estas usando dos clases diferentes *java.sql.Date* y *java.util.Date*

Por otro lado te comparto un metodo generico que te podria servir, donde solo especificas el formato en estas pasando la fecha y obviamente la fecha a convertir

```
public static Date getDateFormat(String formatPattern, String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(formatPattern)
    return formatter.parse(date)
}
```

Sin embargo te recomiendo que hagas uso de la clase *java.time.LocalDateTime* si estas usando java8 o superior

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciona para mi

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.sql.Date fechaConvertida=null;

try {
    Date parsed =  dateFormat.parse(startDate);
    fechaConvertida = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred"+ e.getMessage());
}
```